# Table with a for loop and formatting

Tags: java

```
    System.out.println("Year     StartBalance     Interest Earned      End Balance");
    for (int i = 1; i<Years+1; i++) { //table: year number, principal at beginning, total interest earned, principal at the end
        double AmountPerQuarter = (Principal * (1 + Rate/400));
        NewPrincipal = AmountPerQuarter;
        double InterestEarned = NewPrincipal - Principal;
        System.out.printf(i+ "%13s %15s %22s",Principal,InterestEarned,NewPrincipal);
        Principal = NewPrincipal;
    }
```

Hi, I'm a computer science student and I was a little bit confused on formatting in this example.

What this is supposed to do is, create the the table with Year, StartBalance, etc on the top, and then print the segment out as one line, and then when the loop repeats, it would start a new line, but using printf, everything the loop does is just printed on one line, which counteracts what I'm trying to do with the table.

For example, it ends up like:

```
Year   StartBalance     InterestEarned      Endbalance

1..........500................20............520252040580
```

instead of starting a new line for the second year.

Also, as a side question, when I'm using formatting like "%13s" to create 13 spaces, how would I make it so what it prints is rounded to two decimal places? I know "%.2f" is whats used, but I'm not sure how I would combine both of them so I can create 13 spaces and have the number with rounded decimal spaces.

I'm sorry if this seems unclear, I've tried searching but couldn't find an answer.

Thank you!

Comment: Use `\n` for a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new line, you need a **new line character**, which could be created by adding `\n` or using a blank `System.out.println("");` (which creates a new line character). Here's the former:

Change

```
System.out.printf(i+ "%13s %15s %22s",Principal,InterestEarned,NewPrincipal);
```

To

```
System.out.printf(i+ "%13s %15s %22s\n",Principal,InterestEarned,NewPrincipal);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `%n` for newline, also an integer is `%d`. Something like

```
System.out.printf("%12d %13s %15s %22s%n", i, Principal, InterestEarned, 
        NewPrincipal);
```